# angular UI multiple popovers, close single programatically after submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, angular-ui

I am trying to programmatically close open popover based on index after submit is done.

html on a page:

```
<a role="button" uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" 
   popover-is-open="isPopoverOpen[$index]" ng-click="openPopover($index)>                 
open popover
</a>
```

popover template:

```
<input ng-model="input.value">
<button class="btn" ng-click="saveValue()">submit</button>
```

controller:

```
$scope.openPopover = openPopover;
$scope.saveValue = saveValue;

$scope.dynamicPopover = {
    templateUrl: 'templates/test_popup.html'
};

function openPopover(index){
    $scope.isPopoverOpen[index] = true;
    $scope.popIndex = index;
}

function saveValue(index){

    var data = {
        value: $scope.input.value
    }

    $http.post('url', data)
        .then(function (res) {

           $scope.isPopoverOpen[$scope.popIndex] = false;

        }, function (err) {

        });

    }
}
```

all of this works except closing popover when ajax is done, so is this even possible ?

Comment: How many popovers are there ?

Comment: currently I have up to 4, as I have up to 4 list elements

Comment: When you are initialising $scope.isPopoverOpen[index] = false; the index is the correct one? And ur openPopover(index) should be defined on $scope

Comment: it looks like index is undefined for second one, function is fine I forgot to add it above...testing to fix index

Comment: You forgot to add $scope for both functions. How will u bind it to view without using $scope?

Comment: it's added in my code,here I forgot to place it...functions work but passing index to the second one is undefined

Comment: Update your question with fixed code if possible. Stuff like `saveValue()` not being passed `index`.

Comment: updated and after passing the correct index it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save index and use it in your saveValue function

**JS**:

```
$scope.openPopover(index){
    $scope.isPopoverOpen[index] = true;
    $scope.selectedIndex = index;
}

 $scope.saveValue=function(){

        var data = {
            value: $scope.input.value
        }

        $http.post('url', data)
            .then(function (res) {

               $scope.isPopoverOpen[$scope.selectedIndex ] = false;

            }, function (err) {

            });

        }
    }
```

Comment: already done, thanks...I was obviously very tired so I did not debug index.